# mutt: two character sequence commands

Tags: mutt, key-mapping

Is there any way to define a two-sequence command in the mutt email client?

I would like to map `gg` to the first email, similar to the first line on vim, but I can only find ways to map commands to single keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
bind pager gg           top
bind index gg           first-entry
```

See the [manual on keybindings](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.3):

> key is the key (**or key sequence**) you wish to bind.

Comment: Wow, I should have just given it a try! Thanks very much.

Comment: @marshall.ward no problem. I have quite few vim bindings in [my muttrc](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/tip/.mutt/muttrc)...